# Syntax error in print statement

Tags: python

This is the end of my script. I'm getting the error :

```
print "[%s]\t %s " % (item.sharing['access'], item.title)
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Code:

```
#List titles and sharing status for items in users'home folder
 for item in currentUser.items:
     print "[%s]\t %s " % (item.sharing['access'], item.title)
```

**Questions**

How can I correct this syntax error?

Where can I access resources to avoid mistakes such as this?

Comment: is it python 2 or python3?

Comment: Paste more of  your code; as it stands the syntax in these two lines looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

Either you're using Python 3, in which `print` is a function and thus requires surrounding parentheses (i.e. you have to say `print(x)` instead of `print x`), or you have an earlier line of code that wasn't terminated properly.

Comment: @Chris_Rands Assuming you mean "omit parentheses from a print statement", __yes it does__.

Comment: It explicitly says `SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'` rather than `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: @Chris_Rands If it's a simple statement like `print 5`, yes you're right.  But not if it's a more complex statement like `print "hello %s %s" % ("bill", "smith")`, _such as is used in the example code_.